# reverse procedure of KroneckerProduct

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

We know that the `KroneckerProduct` of two matrices `a` and `b` will be done as

```
a = {{2, 1}, {I, 3}}; b = {{2, 3, 1}, {1, 4, 6}, {2, 4, 6}};
m=KroneckerProduct[a,b]
(**{{4, 6, 2, 2, 3, 1}, {2, 8, 12, 1, 4, 6}, {4, 8, 12, 2, 4, 6}, {2 I, 
3 I, I, 6, 9, 3}, {I, 4 I, 6 I, 3, 12, 18}, {2 I, 4 I, 6 I, 6, 12, 
18}}**
```

Is there any defined reverse procedure by which if we have a given matrix such as `m` we be able to access `a` and `b`?!

Comment: The certainly won't be a unique solution. It is ambiguous at least to a multiplicative factor.

Comment: @ J. M.  thank you so much for your suggested address, I must read that carefully to understand what happened.